# request.auth != null and request.auth == null give no access, where true does - firebase stoarge

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, firebase-security, angularfire

I am using AngularFire and Firebase 8.10.0 to access files on storage (avatar images to be used in IMG - so URLs).

Edit: **Failing code** - getting the files is done via

```
<img [src]='user.photoURL'>
```

Which results in an 403 GET error:

> images%2FIFjwtbvRjwbeIVYJlCYuHMdhfTA3%2FphotoURL.jpg:1 GET
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kuyua-2199c.appspot.com/o/images%2FIFjwtbvRjwbeIVYJlCYuHMdhfTA3%2FphotoURL.jpg?alt=media&token=e2d7e4ac-477b-4e79-8f7b-ece826f9b67a
> 403

And the URL giving:

```
   {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
      }
    }
```

The Firebase Storage rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
 
    match /images/{userId}/{imageId} {
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 0.5 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                   && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read:  if  request.auth != null;
    }
 }
}
```

Some tries:

1. If I change to the following, the URL loads perfectly:

   allow read:  if  true;

Knowing about an earlier issue with auth and rules, I wondered if testing for null would work, but that also does not yield anything

```
allow read:  if  request.auth == null;
```

Using the emulator, the rules function properly.

2. Another try:

A get to

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kuyua-2199c.appspot.com/o/images%2FIFjwtbvRjwbeIVYJlCYuHMdhfTA3%2FphotoURL.jpg?alt=media&token=84138d8a-b608-45d3-8f17-f9d22d24ae04

Does give the picture, making me wonder it is actually the token that changes the behaviour (that's the only difference between the two urls)? Then, my question is how to relates to the firebase rules?

Anyone having a clue?

Tom
(ps. while writing this, I think I may need to figure out why it is working for the products, but not the avatars, nevertheless, all help is welcome)

Comment: Rules on themselves don't do anything, so I recommend editing your question to show the minimal code that is failing. In that case, just before loading the image, I recommend logging the current user's UID, because that is likely to be the problem.

Comment: Thx @FrankvanPuffelen. I edited the question. I think I am getting errors because the token on the downloadURL has changed. Can it be that if the rules says "allow read: if true" it does affects the way firebase looks at the token? (as you said, the rules do not do anything). Makes me also want to know the content of request.auth. I am not sure if it is possible to inspect that one. Thx for your help.  Rule now is :     allow read: if imageId == "photoURL.jpg"; which works nicely

Answer (score 1):

A download URL gives public, read-only access to the underlying file. So accessing an image in Cloud Storage through its download URL, does not lead to a check of the security rules.

If the only difference between the working and non-working URL is in the `token` in there, it's most likely that the token of non-working URL was revoked through the Firebase console.

Comment: Thank you. If you say the downloadURL does not lead to a check of security rules, I still wonder why I get a broken url when I do a check on auth in the rules, whereas, when I put it on "allow read:always true", the links work.